# Include libraries into my project folder

Tags: c++, qt-creator, libraries

I'm programming using C++ and Qt Creator. I need to include the libraries I'm using inside my project folder so that the program can be implemented on any device. What should I do exactly?

I know I should modify the `.pro` file and I already tried this:

```
LIBS+=-L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/libs" \
-lvl \
```

But it does not work. I get this error:
error while loading shared libraries: libvl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Doesn't the compiler find the libs? If `lvl` is a lib, you need to add an `-l` prefix to actually add it to the list of libs to link against.

Comment: It gives this error:
error while loading shared libraries: libvl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @thokra yes i already have it as -lvl in my program but when i made copy paste into the forum the - was gone :D

Comment: I already corrected the question

Comment: @triple13: Well, obviously liblv isn't located at `$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/libs`. Put out a message and print the path and check if the fiel exists where you expect it to exist.

Comment: @thokra Its is there for sure.I checked some references then i tried to add the library automatically in QT Creator and here is what Qt Creator made to the .pro file:

`unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lvl

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libs`

But im still getting the same result.

Comment: But you do get a *link time* error, right? Or are we talking *runtime error*?

Comment: @thokra no im getting runtime error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, on Linux qmake generates Makefiles which are used to control your build process. When you add the line

```
LIBS+=-L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/libs" -lvl
```

to your `.pro` file, qmake will see to it that appropriate Makefile target is generated which tells the linker to search for additional libraries in `$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/libs` and link to a library `libvl.so` when *linking* the executable.

However what you're experiencing is a *run-time* problem. More specifically, `ld-linux.so.2` will try to find and dynamically load shared libraries like `libvl.so` at *runtime*. This happens using built-in, such as `/usr/lib` and user-defined (and/or distribution-defined) paths when the executable is loaded. I refer you to the corresponding [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) for `ld-linux.so.2` and the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) for `ldconfig`, which is used to configure user-defined library search paths in a standard way.

When `ld-linux.so.2` tries to find libraries, it searches a well defined set of directories (all colon-separated) in the following order:

- if present, the so called `DT_RPATH`, which can be written into an executable library (**deprecated**).
- the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (at least for most executables, see the man page for exceptions)
- the `DT_RUNPATH` which supersedes the `DT_RPATH` (if any) but delays lookup until after `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has been processed. The `RPATH` and `RUNPATH` can be used to simulate behavior like on Windows, where the path of the executable is also searched. `LD_LIBRARy_PATH`, however, is much better suited for this purpose.
- library names present in the cache file `/etc/ld.so.cache` which is generated by `ldconfig` using directories specified in `/etc/ld.so.conf/` and possibly additional files either directly referred to via inclusion in `ld.so.conf` or otherwise specified
- the *trusted directories*, `/lib` and `/usr/lib`

If none of the paths mentioned above contain the appropriate shared object, you will get an error that it could not be loaded by `ld-linux.so.2`.

The solution in your case is simple and come in some variety:

- before executing the program, set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH={yourSearchPaths}`.
- add the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the invocation of the executable on the command-line, e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH={yourSearchPaths} ./{executable}`
- provide an executable start-up shell script, e.g. `start.sh`, which does the above for you and then simply execute the shell-script `./start.sh`

Comment: What is it with people down-voting without a comment?

Comment: @thokra..thanks so much for the detailed explanation..i changed the line in the .pro file to: 'LIBS+=-L"$$PWD/libs" -lvl' and it did not work..i tried the whole project on another device..and here is the suprise..it works perfectly..even though everything is the same in both devices..maybe just QT Creator version is different..anyway thanks so much :)

Comment: @triple13: What do you mean with *device*? Also, QtCreator simply parses the `.pro` file an does stuff in the IDE accordingly. QtCreator does *not* contribute at build-time or run-time (other than launching the executable and possibly specifying a working directory).

Comment: @thokra..by device i mean another machine..another computer..i tried the same project and it worked