# Qt Creator: cannot open shared object file after moving library to subdir

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I have a project where the library sources were set up the following way:

```
MyProject  
 |_MyProject.pro
 |_MainStuff 
   |_MainStuff.pro
   |_ManyFiles
 |_Tests  
   |_Tests.pro
   |_LotsOfTests
 |_MyLibs  
   | FunLibs.pro
   |_FunLib1.h  
   |_FunLib1.cpp  
   |_FunLib2.h  
   |_FunLib2.cpp
```

This is not ideal, because as the number of FunLibs increases, all of it would be included into a single shared object. With this setup, everything builds and runs just fine. Just to be clear: MyProject.pro is a subdirs template, the MainStuff.pro is an app template, and the FunLibs is a lib template.

The problem stats, when I rearrange the files the following way:

```
MyProject  
 |_MainStuff  
   |_ ManyFiles
 |_Tests  
   |_LotsOfTests
 |_MyLibs 
   |_MyLibs.pro 
   |_FunLib1  
     |_FunLib1.pro
     |_FunLib1.h  
     |_FunLib1.cpp  
   |_FunLib2  
     |_FunLib2.pro  
     |_FunLib2.h  
     |_FunLib2.cpp
```

Here the MyLibs.pro becomes a subdir tempalte, while the FunLibx.pro files will be lib templates. All configurations have been updated accordingly and the application builds. The problem is that when I now try to launch the application, the following message pops up:

> libFunLib1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I don't really understand why doesn't it work now, when it worked with the previous directory structure. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977420/include-libraries-into-my-project-folder) post for example (as many others) recommends to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH by exporting the dir, but to be honest, I didn't have to do this with the previous setup.

I also have everything set up pretty much as described in the [official docs](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) under the "Creating a shared library" part.

Does anybody have an idea what might be the problem? Is there a way to solve this by not exporting the path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do the built lib binaries (.so files) end up? I'm guessing they used to be on the same level with the executable (or whatever loads them at runtime) and now they're in subfolders of the build tree and can't be found by default. If that's the case, one thing you could do is specify where the resulting binaries end up by explicitly setting the `qmake` `DESTDIR` variable in the project files.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found out what can fix the aforementioned problem. Qt Creator also uses LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable for executing compiled programs, but it is somewhat hidden. As it turns out, it is able to use separate sets of env variables for compiling and running applications, and if the env vars for running are not properly defined, the user will get the error message mentioned in the original post, even if the program compiled properly.

To make sure all lib paths are included for running as well, one needs to check out the included paths here:

> Projects (mode) --> Run Settings (under Build & Run) -->  Run
>   Environment (expand the Details) --> LD_LIBRARY_PATH (somewhere in the
>   list)

If that var doesn't include the proper paths, it can be edited after which it is going to get highlighted. After setting this, everything seems to work.